# ¿Cómo pido datos desde php a una base de datos en MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql-workbench

Tengo una base de datos con una serie de preguntas y respuestas que necesito poner en una pagina web. Ya cree la base de datos. ¿Como hago ahora para que me muestre la pregunta y las respuestas en la pagina web? Sé que se hace con PHP el enlace a MySQL pero no sé como.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: te recomiendo buscar en google.com existen muchos tutoriales, incluso youtube, aqui esta uno: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: @KacosPro Copié el código en el editor Sublime y lo guardé. Cuando lo voy a probar aparece el mismo código en el navegador. Me ayudas con eso por fa? Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Para acceder a los datos dentro de una base de datos MySQL, primero hay que conectarse al servidor de la base de datos MySQL. PHP ofrece dos formas diferentes de conectarse al servidor MySQL: extensiones MySQLi (MySQL mejorado) y PDO (objetos de datos PHP).

Si bien la extensión PDO es más portátil y admite más de doce bases de datos diferentes, la extensión MySQLi, como su nombre lo indica, solo admite la base de datos MySQL. Sin embargo, la extensión de MySQL proporciona una forma más fácil de conectarse y ejecutar consultas en un servidor de base de datos MySQL. Tanto PDO como MySQLi ofrecen una API orientada a objetos, pero MySQLi también ofrece una API de procedimientos que es relativamente fácil de entender para los principiantes.

**Conexión al servidor de base de datos MySQL**

En PHP se puede hacer esto fácilmente usando la función mysqli_connect (). Toda la comunicación entre PHP y el servidor de base de datos MySQL se lleva a cabo a través de esta conexión. Acá están las sintaxis básicas para conectarse a MySQL usando extensiones MySQLi y PDO:

**Syntaxis: MySQLi, Procedural**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("nombredehost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basededatos");
```

**Syntaxis: MySQLi, orientado a objetos**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("nombredehost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basededatos");
```

**Syntaxis: PDO**

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=nombredehost;dbname=basededatos", "usuario", "contraseña");
```

El parámetro de `nombredehost` en la sintaxis anterior especifica el nombre de host (por ejemplo, localhost) o la dirección IP del servidor MySQL, mientras que los parámetros de `usuario` y `contraseña` especifican las credenciales para acceder al servidor MySQL, y el parámetro de `basededatos` especificará la base de datos MySQL predeterminada que se utilizará al realizar consultas.

El siguiente ejemplo muestra cómo conectarse al servidor de base de datos MySQL usando MySQLi de forma procedural.

```
<?php
/*  configuración default (usuario 'root' sin password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

// Chequeo la conexión
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Error al conectar. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Impriir información del host
echo "Conectado. Info: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link);
?>
```

Si se imprime la respuesta con la info del host, lograste conectar a la base MYSQL.

Comment: y si no? No me sale nada. :(